# AngularJS Best practices to use $rootscope?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angularjs-rootscope

I'm a beginner in angular and I try to do this tutorial ( http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/ )

I use the best practices by John Papa. So, i don't use $scope but a variable.
**var vm = this;** on my controller and ui-router.

But on this tutorial, at one moment, he use $rootScope. I have seen that it's bad practice but sometimes you have to use.

On this tutorial, have you another possibility without $rootScope or you haven't choice?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I quickly checked the link and noted that $rootScope is used to hold the currentUser property. This kind of things are better with services and factories, I try not to use $rootScope at all, though the temptation is strong.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, that using of `$rootScope` is not a good practice.

As I understand, in this tutorial he uses `$rootScope` just for storing `currentUser` on `login` (and remove on `logout`). That's it.

And this case could be easily implemented without using `$rootScope` at all. It will require a bit more code, but it's not so difficult.

If you ok to write a bit more code and make you code without using bad practices then you can do something the following:

You can create a separated service:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
       .service('UserKeeper', function($) {
           var userKeeper = {
               currentUser:{}
           };

           return userKeeper;
        });
```

and then just inject this service in your `Auth` factory and save your user in `currentUser` property instead of saving it in your `$rootScope`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's perfect !